# Download PHP PDO SQLite Database Create in Memory

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo, download

I first create a database using the SQLite PDO library like so.

```
$sqlite = new PDO("sqlite::memory:");
```

I then do everything I want to do to setup the database.

**My Question**

How do I then begin this sqlite database downloading to the user?

Comment: Backup it to a file and supply it?

Comment: @LS_dev so I may as well just create the database as a file anyway?